# Why does VS2013 reset my vertically split XAML windows?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

Whenever I look at a XAML file, I always split them vertically (design surface on the left, XAML on the right), as I find it much easier to work this way.

Usually, when I close and reopen VS, the setting is remembered, however fairly often VS just forgets it, and opens them all split horizontally.

Anyone any idea why it does this?

Comment: Do you ever work with more than one copy of Visual Studio open at a time?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Yes I sometimes do, but never on the same solution. As far as I can see, VS (supposedly) remembers the split settings on a file-by-file basis, so I wouldn't have thought this would be the problem. Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can set the default to split vertically from

Tools > Options > XAML Designer:

- Default document view : split
- Split Orientation: vertical

Comment: That's exactly what I want, except that I don't have a XAML Designer node under Options. Is this from an add-in? If not, how come I don't see it? I'm using VS2013 Ultimate update 4. Thanks

Comment: I got that from my copy of Visual Studio 2015, I don't have 2013 installed on this computer any more, but I can check when I get in to work in the morning.  I don't think it came from any addon.

Comment: I just verified that the option is NOT in Visual Studio 2013. Looks like it's time for an upgrade.